LID Design - Layout and Concepts
I have a general but important question regarding LID design. I work as the only civil engineer at my company, and I have rarely used LID design in my projects. I am trying to familiarize myself with them as they are clearly a great way to integrate the storm design with the aesthetics of the landscape design, while also providing great treatment/flow control options at a potentially lower cost to my clients.
In general, I can learn a lot about these from online sources, design guides, and stormwater manuals, but I have found so far they really just get into sizing and detailed calculations. The challenge for me has been finding the best way to integrate these systems into the site.  Most LID systems appear to be surface-level while most of my past designs have included underground pipes, which then lead to another underground system, and this makes the site grading pretty straightforward since you can use the pipes to direct the stormwater to your BMP's. With LID's, it seems to me that you almost always need to sheet flow directly into the systems, and that can be challenging with complex sites; also with buildings and sites without much fall.
Does anyone know of any way to learn from experts or people that have been doing this type of design for a long time, some techniques or best practices when it comes to site layout, LID selection, and general site design for these types of systems. If anyone knows of any webinars, videos, classes, or just discussion groups that can help me learn these system better, please let me know.
I think in general, there isn't enough material for civil engineers like myself who are trying to learn independently.

I really dislike it when people assume everyone else knows the acronyms & abbreviations they are using. What are LID & BMP acronyms for?
